# Three.js - renderer.setSize(width,height) - How is Offset Horizontal and Offset Vertical Specified

Tags: html, css, three.js

I am writing JavaScript with Three.js to use WebGL.

My code calls:

```
renderer.setSize( 100, 100 );
```

The window is much larger than that size.

The rendered scene is placed in the top left corner of the window.

I would like it centered.

**How can I center the rendered scene?**

Comment: you should look into cascading style sheets ([tag:css])

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: I must render to 100 x 100. My application requires that I render to that size and to that aspect ration. Your suggesstion changes both the size of the rendered image and the aspect ratio of the rendered image. My question is "how can I center the image". Is there a "center justification" argument? Or how can I control the horizontal and Vertical offsets of where the rendered image appears in the browser window. And I would need to be able to update those offsets as the window event detects a change in the size of the browser window.